# Navigation to different Page using SENCHA

Tags: sencha-touch

I had rendered a list using SENCHA.Now i want to navigate to different screen/load different screen upon clicking the item in LIST.

```
        var templist = new Ext.List( {
        title:"xmli",
            itemTpl : '{ename}',

                floating: true,
                indexBar: true,
                width: 350,
                height: 370,
                centered: true,
                store:xmlStore,
                modal: true,
                onItemDisclosure: {
                scope: 'test',
                handler: function(record, btn, index) {
              // I need to a load different page here how ?.
                  // ChangePage();
                }
            },
                hideOnMaskTap: false
            }).show();
```

Please help me how can we achieve this using SENCHA.

Thanks,
Shyam

Answer (score 0):

You need to put this list inside a layout where you can switch the visible component to your different page. It sounds like you could use the card layout:

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/layout-browser/layout-browser.html